# Should the mongocsharpdriver and mongodb-csharp tags be merged?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

While asking a question related to the MongoDB C# Driver I noticed that there were two very similar tags that are listed below with their descriptions.

1. [mongocsharpdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongocsharpdriver)

   > The official MongoDB .NET Driver provides asynchronous interaction with MongoDB.
2. [mongodb-csharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-csharp)

   > The MongoDB C# Driver is the officially supported C#/.NET driver for MongoDB.

In my opinion these are one and the same and should be merged. The latter has 1.5k questions compared to less than 100 for the former so would recommend sticking with the higher of the two.

I also noticed [mongodb-csharp-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-csharp-driver) which seems to have similar numbers to [mongodb-csharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-csharp) - is this just an alias as it's naming seems the best of the three.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the page URL is http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/, the official name of the product is *MongoDB .NET Driver*. Keeping in line with tags like [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), I propose using [mongodb-.net-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-.net-driver). We'd need help from a moderator then to set synonyms or do a tag merge.

Comment: "We'd need help from a moderator" Do we hope that one comes along? Or do I have to flag the question?

Comment: @rrrr Pretty much yes, after community consensus is reached, we hope that one comes along. MSO is used for a myriad of things, often in a good enough way but not at all in an ideal way.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your and Stijn's arguments, the following tag merges have been performed and synonyms created:

- [mongodb-.net-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-.net-driver) ← [mongocsharpdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongocsharpdriver)
- [mongodb-.net-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-.net-driver) ← [mongo-csharp-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-csharp-driver)
- [mongodb-.net-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-.net-driver) ← [mongodb-csharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-csharp)
- [mongodb-.net-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-.net-driver) ← [mongodb-csharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-csharp)

Thoughts on [mongodb-csharp-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-csharp-2.0)? Should this become [monodb-.net-driver-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monodb-.net-driver-2.0)?

Comment: Based on the release date of v2.0 being back in 2015 I would suggest that `mongodb-csharp-2.0` should be merged in to `mongodb-.net-driver`. I can't imagine anyone will still be raising cases against v1.