# What should I do about an overlooked merge suggestion?

Tags: discussion, support

A few months back [I posted a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336146/should-the-mongocsharpdriver-and-mongodb-csharp-tags-be-merged) regarding tags that I thought should be merged. It received a couple of upvotes but no answers and it doesn't look like anything has changed with the tags.

What are the next steps? Is raising a question like this correct or should I be doing something else?

If this was on the main site I might raise a bounty, that doesn't seem to be a thing on here.

Comment: The same question was asked [a few days ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341020/make-mongocsharpdriver-a-synonym-for-mongodb-csharp), too. No one caught it as a duplicate at that time, although I've since voted to close it as one.